# How to get text data from the user in PL/SQL block

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get text data from the user when the if conditions are true,

Please tell me how to do this in PL/SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the conditions in question are known before you call from your user interface to the PL/SQL code.  If this is the case, test the conditions before the call to PL/SQL (in the user interface).  If necessary, get the text from the user, then call into your PL/SQL and pass the text.

Comment: I'he tried but the user interface in this case is Business Intelligence (I'm trying to generate a report, if variable of the report meet the condiction then I want to get text data from the user in order for him to justify the action he's doing)but I don't know how to conbine them.

Comment: You are not going to be able to interact with the user, directly, from PL/SQL.  Let that go.  Instead, you must get the required information before calling the report generation PL/SQL.